# Современный вариант книги: "Энциклопедия профессора Фортрана"

Tags: книги

Детская книжка-комикс "Энциклопедия профессора Фортрана", возможно, одна из причин, почему почти 30 лет спустя StackOverflow стал одним из моих любимых сайтов.

Содержание ее, конечно во многом, устарело, но, как мне видится, не ее дух, и поэтому хотелось бы дать детям что-либо подобное и современное.

Существует ли современный вариант "[Энциклопедии профессора Фортрана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)", неважно, отечественный или зарубежный?

[image: Энциклопедия профессора Фортрана]

Формальные критерии, чтобы избежать закрытия вопроса как "опросника":

- доступная форма изложения (комикс или много картинок)
- объяснены "классические" понятия, в первую очередь, что такое алгоритм, язык программирования, ввод-вывод, может, даже операционная система.
- научно-техническая достоверность и реалии по состоянию 2019 года, например объяснения, что всякие гаджеты в наше время по сути специализированные мини-компьютеры, например, что такое Интернет, искусственный интеллект.
- важность сообщества разработчиков открытого кода (чем не Компьютерная Страна, хоть ее и не было в Энциклопедии, именно потому что тогда это была не энциклопедийная фантазия, но с тех пор ситуация сильно изменилась)

Comment: Очень здорово, что вы добавили раздел про критерии. Хорошо бы еще как-то защититься от "порождает дискуссии"

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/265787/

Comment: `важность сообщества разработчиков открытого кода` - это взрослым тяжело объяснить. "M$ - это же удобно...". хотя ... по принципу "жулик - не жульничай"

Comment: @Kromster опубликовал

Answer (score 4):

Перечисленным критериям не удовлетворяет ни одна книга в силу стремительного темпа развития ИТ-технологий и ростом объёма новых знаний. Поэтому можно ориентироваться на список книг, раскрывающих тему для детской аудитории:

1. Леонтьев В.П., Детская компьютерная энциклопедия, 2006.
2. Леонтьев В.П., Компьютерная энциклопедия школьника, 2006.
3. Леонтьев В.П., Компьютер. Настольная книга школьника, 2007.
4. Харитонов В.В., Компьютер. Моя первая энциклопедия, 2013.
5. Дуванов А.А., Изучаем компьютер, 2012.
6. Дуванов А.А., Андреева Е.В., Семакин И.Г., Энциклопедия школьной информатики, 2018.
7. Адаменко М.В., Компьютер для современных детей. Настольная книга активного школьника и дошкольника, 2016.
8. Дрейер М., C# для школьников, 2010.
9. Сэнд У., Сэнд К., Hello World! Занимательное программирование, 2016.
10. Файн Я., Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек, 2011.
11. Бриггс Дж., Python для детей. Самоучитель по программированию., 2017.
12. Вордерман К., Вудкок Дж., Макаманус Ш., Программирование для детей. Иллюстрированное руководство по языкам Scratch и Python,
13. Винницкий Ю.А., Поляков К.Ю., Конструируем роботов на ScratchDuino. Первые шаги., 2016.
14. Бейктал Дж., Конструируем роботов на Arduino. Первые шаги., 2016.
15. Ревич Ю., Азбука электроники. Изучаем Arduino., 2017.
16. Колмаков С., Дело в программировании.Пособие по программированию Arduino. 2017.
17. Морган Н., JavaScript для детей. Самоучитель по программированию., 2016.

Answer (score 3):

По некоторым критериям, можно обратить внимание на:

1. Серия "Образовательная манга", а именно книги по Занимательной Информатике.
2. Линда Льюкас., Привет, Руби. Сказка с заданиями, которая научит ребенка думать как программист., 2019.
3. Ханс-Георг Шуманн., Python для детей., 2019
4. Тарапата, Прокофьев., Учимся вместе со Scratсh. Программирование, игры, робототехника., 2019.
5. Джереми Мориц., Учимся кодить на JavaScript., 2019.
6. Шон Макманус., Программист. Детская академия., 2019.
7. Эл Свейгарт., Программирование для детей. Делай игры и учи язык Scratch., 2017.
8. Елена Зорина., Путешествие в страну Алгоритмию с котенком Скретчем., 2016.
9. Михаэль Вайгенд., Raspberry PI для детей., 2019.